# Passing move-only function arguments to boost::thread constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, boost-thread

The following works for `std::thread`. It prints 10 as output, which is what I desire.

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<int> && in) {
  std::cout << *in;
}

int main(){
  auto in = std::make_unique<int>(10);
  std::thread t(foo, std::move(in));
  t.join();
}
```

But, similar attempt with Boost 1.72 fails to compile

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<int> && in) {
    std::cout << *in;
}

int main(){

    auto in = std::make_unique<int>(10);
    boost::thread t(foo, std::move(in));
    t.join();
}
```

> ```
> Error : note: copy constructor of 'list1<boost::_bi::value<std::unique_ptr<int>>>' is implicitly deleted because base class 'storage1<boost::_bi::value<std::unique_ptr<int>>>' has a deleted copy constructor
> template< class A1 > class list1: private storage1< A1 >
> ```

I find this surprising, because the documentation for boost::thread states the following :

> Thread Constructor with arguments
> template <class F,class A1,class A2,...>
> thread(F f,A1 a1,A2 a2,...);

> Preconditions:
> F and each An must be copyable or movable.

Since I am passing a `std::unique_ptr` as argument, I am meeting the 'movable' criterion. So, I wonder why is boost thread constructing the `std::unique_ptr`? Shouldn't it move the std::unique_ptr into the thread object, and then move it further into the thread function like the implementation for `std::thread` does?

Comment: Hmm.... Cant seem to edit my post... I meant to write 'I wonder why is boost thread COPY constructing the std::unique_ptr'

Comment: Can we have the complete error message?

Answer (score 1):

Per documentation, `boost::thread` uses the arguments in exactly the same way `boost::bind` does, and this combination of function and argument is unsuitable for `boost::bind` (and for `std::bind` for that matter).

```
std::bind(foo, std::move(in))(); // error
boost::bind(foo, std::move(in))(); // error
```

`std::thread` is more robust than either `std::bind` or `boost::bind`.

If you need to move the argument to `foo`, you need to wrap it in a function or a lambda that accepts it by non-const lvalue reference and moves it to `foo`. Otherwise, just change `foo` to accept a non-const lvalue reference argument.

Comment: Actually `std::bind` works, except it doesn't pass an rvalue to `foo`: https://godbolt.org/z/q3efKb

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont There are two different meanings of `&&`. `std::bind` works with the one you have used, but not with the other one.

Comment: Is aid it doesn't pass an rvalue.  (The two different meanings of `&&` are the and operator and an rvalue reference; reference collapsing makes you rvalue reference deduce an lvalue reference.  You could call the package of reference collapding and template argument type deduction a different meaning of `&&`, but then there would be 3.  4 if you split short-circuit from non-short circuit operator `&&`. Regardless, std bind works with move only types; and the "more robustness" of std thread is because the callable is executed *once*; the same logic on std bind would be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in **Boost.Thread** documentation. By default it doesn't support move-only arguments since it passes them through to `boost::bind` by-value instead of forwarding.

But there's a flag `BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_VARIADIC_THREAD` that enables `boost::thread` rvalue-constructors. It is set automatically when another poorly documented variable, `BOOST_THREAD_VERSION` > 4.

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 5
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
. . .
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JiUyAsAWxAyyZYed)

Another possible workaround is to use a lambda.

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<int> in) {
    std::cout << *in;
}

int main() {
    auto in = std::make_unique<int>(10);
    boost::thread t([in = std::move(in)]() mutable { foo(std::move(in)); });
    t.join();
}
```

[Live demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fHCPcLWwJKZrYX7t)

Answer (score 0):

The boost thread library uses boost bind, and boost bind assumes you can call the callable repeatedly, so doesn't move out of it.  You can fake it.

```
template<class T>
struct move_it_t {
  T t;
  operator T(){ return std::move(t); }
};
template<class T>
move_it_t<typename std::decay<T>::type> move_it(T&& t)
  return std::move(t);
};
```

then

```
auto in = std::make_unique<int>(10);
boost::thread t(foo, move_it(in));
t.join();
```

what this does is wrap `in` in a type that, when cast to `T`, moves instead of copies.